# How can I solve this access denied error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Answer (score 0):

This question need more context, try explaining what you are doing and when this error pops up.

Also use Code snippet to add some code.

FCB Open failed might be a Windows related issue where SQL Server does not have appropriate permission to the folder that contains the master database file and hence the error. Try checking permissions.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107514/fcbopen-failed-could-not-open-file) can help.